# iterator.hasNext() returns wrong value

Tags: java, list, recursion

I'm trying to use a an iterator in a recursive method. It should exit the method if there is no next element left in the list. But if the cursor are at the last position the check with `iterator.hasNext()` return `true`, I except `false`?

Any ideas and hints?

I'm not albe to post image so I will write it down. That's what I'm seeing in the Eclipse-Debugger-View:

```
iterator             | AbstractList$Itr (id=448)

 - cursor            | 2
 - excpectedModCount | 2
 - lastRet           | 1
 - this$0            | ArrayList<E> (id=438)
 - elemtData         | Object[10] (id=462)

 ---modCount         | 2

 ---size             | 2
```

Here's the code

```
static void resolveWithIterator(List<SomethingContext> list, Iterator<ContextResolveHelper> iterator, List<ContextResolveHelper> resolverList)
{
    boolean end = resolverList.iterator().hasNext();
    if (list.size() == 1 || !end){
        resolvedList.add(list);
        return;
    }else{
        ContextResolveHelper acutalEntry = iterator.next();
    List<SomethingContext> tempQRes2 = new ArrayList<SomethingContext>();
        for (SomethingContext smtCtx : list){
            if (//check various things){
                tempQRes2.add(smtCtx);
            }
        }
        resolveWithIterator(tempQRes2, iterator, resolverList);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste code exposing your problem?

Comment: It sounds like you're interpreting implementation details - such as the meaning of the field `cursor`. Is it returning *observably incorrect* values?

Comment: As a parameters you pass iterator and resolverList, is this an iterator over the resolverList?

Comment: Yes this is call of the resolve-Method    'Iterator<ContextResolveHelper> iterator = resolverList.iterator();
   
resolveWithIterator(searchCtxResult, iterator, resolverList);'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in the logic itself, as you wrote, you call the function with:

```
Iterator<ContextResolveHelper> iterator = resolverList.iterator();    
resolveWithIterator(searchCtxResult, iterator, resolverList);
```

but, in the method itself you do 2 separate things, you check next on new iterator, not the provided one

```
boolean end = resolverList.iterator().hasNext();
```

which will return true always when there's at least one element.

Calling iterator() always return new iterator, you should probably use the one provided in the parameter.

Comment: oooooohhhh! Thanks I missed the forest for the trees! Thats right, if I check the right Object all went fine.

Answer (score 1):

The only `hasNext()` I see is `resolverList.iterator().hasNext()`. Since you get a new iterator every time, of course it will always have a "next", unless the list itself is empty.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand. I think I allways give the same iterator-Object to the next recursive-method-call?

Comment: You do pass an iterator recursively, but that's not the iterator that you call hasNext() on.

Comment: Yes now I see my fault, thanks and sorry for the dumb question!